# error occored The connection was not closed The connection current state is open

Tags: c#, ado.net

My code is like this : I input the caseid in the textbox and try to click Find button to find the corresponding result. But Visual studio always says :error occored The connection was not closed The connection current state is open.

This is my first time design ADO.NET myself and I need to finish my advisor research tasks.

Could you check the code and tell me what wrong?

Thanks
Sophia

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace casestudy
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      SqlConnection vcon1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SOPHIA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=casestudy;Integrated Security=True");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                vcon1.Open();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error.occured" + ex.Message);
                this.Dispose();
            }

        }
        private void Find_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string querystring = "SELECT * FROM AssignedSolution WHERE CASEID = @caseid";
            SqlCommand Vcom = new SqlCommand(querystring, vcon1);
            Vcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caseid", txtCASEID);
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;

            try
            {
                Vcom.Connection = vcon1;
                vcon1.Open();
                Vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //DataSet vds1 = new DataSet();
                rdr = Vcom.ExecuteReader();
                //vDa1.Fill(vds1, "res");
                //dataGridView1.DataSource = vds1.Tables["res"];
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);

                }
                Vcom.Dispose();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error.occured" + ex.Message);

            }

            finally
            {
                vcon1.Close();
                vcon1.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is almost the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519879/ado-net-programming-says-error-occured-executenonquery-requires-an-open-and-av/36522428#36522428

Answer (score 1):

The connection is being opened on `Form1_Load` event, then you are trying to open the same connection again in the `Find_Click` event. You can't open a connection that is already open. Just remove all code from the load event, you don't need it.